# why Like condition not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a string table like

`Arun To Raise Up To $400 Million Via Corporate Bonds`

my serach keyword like

`$id='Arun To Raise Up To  400 Million Via Corporate Bonds'`

i write the query for search the keyword from db like

```
News::Where('title', 'like', '%' . $id. '%')->get();
```

I try like in many way but not working and no data will get, how we will solve this issue?

Comment: You probably want something like https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout for this sort of search. `WHERE LIKE` isn't going to handle things like spacing/punctuation differences very well; it's for much simpler searches like returning "Christopher" for a search term of "Chris".

Comment: If your only difference is a `$`, why not simply update your keyword to include the `$` and do a `::where('title', $id)`? Also, sidenote, `$id` is a horrible variable name for this... `$id` should be a single numeric `id`, not a string. If I looked at your code without knowing what `$id` was, I would have no idea why you'd be doing this over say `News::find($id)`.

Comment: @TimLewis sorry $id keyword i update my code

Comment: Thanks for the update, but that was a sidenote, i.e. not relevant to the question being asked. I agree with ceejayoz; a `LIKE` is not the correct function here, as `LIKE` will not work with your keyword and what is in your database... `LIKE` is for simple searches, i.e. `WHERE email LIKE '%@test.com'` will find all `email` column values that end in `@test.com`. You'll need to lookup different search methods (Scout, Elastic, etc.) and see which best fits your needs.